# Why does importing from a module from the current directory only work when within that directory?

Tags: import, python-3.x, python-import, pep

#### Background

I have a Python project with this directory structure:

```
py/:
db/  __init__.py  run.py

py/db:
handle.py  __init__.py  util.py
```

The files are simple enough that I'm not sure I need to post them; nevertheless:

**py/run.py**

```
from db.handle import Handle
```

**py/db/handle.py**:

```
import util

class Handle:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = util.addtwo(x)
```

**py/db/util.py**:

```
def addtwo(x):
    return x + 2
```

If I run `handle.py` from within the `db` subdirectory, it imports `util` without error. However, when I run `run.py`, `handle.py` fails with an import error. I can guess that `handle.py` is being run in the `py` directory (instead of `py/db`), and putting a call to `os.getcwd()` in `handle.py` confirms this. I can fix this problem using `sys.path` like so (in `run.py`):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("db")
from db.handle import Handle
```

#### Question

When importing, from a subdirectory, a module that contains imports to other local modules in that directory, why doesn't Python check the current directory of the module making the import statement? In my example, why doesn't Python check the `db` first when `handle.py` contains import statements? Is there a PEP that describes this or is it a behavior with an obvious rationale that I missed?

I thought it might be related to [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

> all import statements be absolute by default (searching sys.path only) with special syntax (leading dots) for accessing package-relative imports.

but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is "absolute" and  module names is looked for in the PYTHONPATH, and that typically includes the current directory.

If you want to import a module from the same folder that your module is in, you use a relative import:

```
from . import util
```

or

```
from .util import addtwo
```